# webpack vendor chunk regenerates with no changes

Tags: webpack, vendor, code-splitting, commonschunkplugin

I'm code splitting vendor and app into chunks via `CommonsChunkPlugin`. When I build twice I expect the vendor chunk to be unchanged, but it changes :(

Steps to replicate:

1. Clone https://github.com/mattcolman/webpack-vendor-chunk-test
2. Run `yarn`, then `yarn analyzeBundle`, then `yarn analyzeBundle` again.
3. Notice the vendor chunk hash has changed.

The diff between the 2 bundles shows that the `TIME_STAMP` I provide via the `DefinePlugin` is ending up in the vendor chunk, however this code is always inside a code block checking for `"development" === 'test'`, so I would have thought this code gets removed on production.

I actually expected the code for injecting `TIME_STAMP` would end up in the app bundle, that would be fine, but it's not the case.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: ok I found a solution to the problem.

Basically React was also referencing `process.env` in their code. Which meant my variables that I also attached to `process.env` were changing my vendor hash. 

Solution was to move my own variables such a BUILD_VERSION and TIME_STAMP off of `process.env`.

More good info at https://medium.com/webpack/predictable-long-term-caching-with-webpack-d3eee1d3fa31 and https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1315